# XCTest Assertion Failure: Failure requesting automation session

Tags: session, automation, timeout, xctest, assertion

I am trying to run XCUI test cases using following command on one app

```
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun $buildtestxctestrun_file -destination id=badded265a19dea8bxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Xcode Version 10.0
Device iPad Air OS 12.0.1

I have attached the screenshot of error log.

[image]

I can run test cases for different application using same device it works fine.
I am getting this error on this particular application.
Please help me guys.

Comment: I'm seeing sometimes but only when running test cases in parallel.  Did you end up figuring out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for the error.
The IPA file I was using for automation was Distribution IPA file. So it was giving me the error.
I change the ipa file to developer ipa and it was working.